# Question in Vaught's paper

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory

On page 307 of Vaught's paper "Denumerable models of complete theories", theorem 2.1.2 states that there is a denumerable model $\frak{A}$ of $T$ such that if, for each $j\in \omega, \:P_j$ is a non-principal prime ideal (now called ultrafilter) of $F_{p_j+1}(T)$, then there is a denumerable model $\frak{A}$ of $T$ such that $P_0(\mathfrak{A}), P_1(\mathfrak{A}), \cdots$ are all empty. Then Vaught said that 2.1.2 was proved by Ehrenfeucht.

I wonder which of Ehrenfeucht's papers contains theorem 2.1.2.

Comment: I don’t know what would be the original source, but if I guess correctly what all the notation means, then this is just the [omitting types theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Omitting_Types_Theorem) (stated for complete types).

Comment: I know it is (original of) omitting types theorem. It looks like having better form. So omitting types theorem should give some credit to Ehrenfeucht.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Omitting Types Theorem has its roots in the independent work of Leon Henkin and Steven Orey  in  the  early  1950’s on $\omega$-logic.   This  line  of  work  was  advanced  further  by  Andrzej  Grzegorczyk, Andrzej Mostowski, and Czeslaw Ryll-Nardzewski, where a more explicit version of the theorem can be found. The form of the theorem we have used is apparently due to Andrzej Ehrenfeucht around 1955 —- Ehrenfeucht never published his version.
[source](https://people.math.sc.edu/mcnulty/762/modeltheory.pdf)